# A nontrivial tree such that its complement is a maximal planar graph

Tags: graph-theory

A nontrivial tree $T$ of order $n$ has the property that its complement $\overline{T}$ is a maximal planar graph (i.e., a planar graph such that adding any edge makes it nonplanar).

(a) What is $n$?

(b) Give an example of a tree $T$ with this property.

I already figured out that $n$ has to be $7$, but I'm having trouble thinking of a graph that works for this.

Comment: What is $\bar T$?

Comment: The compliment of T.

Comment: Thn pleease explain this in the body of the question. Explaining what you mean by «maximal planar graph» would also be helpful, I guess.

Comment: Maximal planar means that adding another edge would make it not planar.

Comment: As I said, you should edit your question and add all this information *there*.

Comment: Can you give us intuition on how you get $n=7$? In sure the proof would help us to find an example.

Comment: I can feel a solution coming soon.  for now, note that if a graph is maximal planar then the minimum degree is 3.  So, in the complement, the max degree should be 3.  That narrows it down some.  The rest of the solution should rely on the fact that every region is a triangle in the complement of the tree.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a tree for which the complement is maximal planar and the order is 7 (of course the order must be 7, as you have already discovered.)  I started backwards by finding a maximal planar graph with at least 2 vertices of degree 5 (to satisfy the leaves).  Here is the graph of the complement:

[image: Maximal planar graph order 7]

And here is the graph whose complement is maximal planar and pictured above.
  [image: Tree whose complement is maximal planar]

I'm not 100% sure that this is the unique solution.  There could be more, but I think with a little work I could prove this is the unique solution.  I apologize for the sucky drawings as well.

EDIT:

I should also note that for all this to work, we need to not only assume its a non-trivial tree, but also that $n \ge 3$.  This is due to the fact that maximal planar graphs require $n\ge 3$.  If not, then the theorem "If $G$ is a maximal planar graph, then $\delta (G) \ge 3$" holds no water.  ( as well as many more results).  I raise this concern since $n=2$ appears to be a solution to the required number of vertices that are roots of the polynomial $n^2-9n+14$.

Comment: Using `nauty`, we will find the unique solution by `gentreeg 7 |complg |pickg -e15 |planarg`.